Rank data by row across large dataset array in Google Sheets
I have a large array of data where I need to rank the values across each row, and I'm getting stumped. For a given row I can do a simple rank calculation (and expand it across that row with an arrayformula), but what I can't seem to figure out is how to expand this automatically down the array without pulling that formula down to each row.
So, for example for this dataset:



A
B
C
D




$5000
$8000
$2000
$3000


$10000
$3000
$20000
$4000


$7,000
$3,000
$18,000
$1,000



I can rank the first row with =ARRAYFORMULA(rank(A1:D1,$A$1:$D$1)), which gives me:
|A|B|C|D|
|:----|:----|:----|:----|
|2|1|4|3|
However, I'd like the formula to automatically extend down (I have hundreds of rows, and new data gets added regularly) to get the rank across each row like this:



A
B
C
D




2
1
4
3


2
4
1
3


2
3
1
4



I've tried byrow and various other functions, but just can't seem to get it to expand properly. Anyone have any easy ideas?
Thanks in advance for all inputs and help :)


You may try:
=byrow(A2:D,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,map(Σ,lambda(Λ,rank(Λ,Σ))))))


